# Ways to integrate prebid.js in nuxt.js. (Nuxt 2, Vue 2)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, ads, prebid.js, prebid

I am trying to integrate prebid.js in my nuxt application for rendering programmable refresh ad's that uses header biding.
From the official documentation i can see that they are using prebid.js cdn and loading the ad's.

But the best way is to download and use it. I tried to download and use it as a plugin in nuxt. I am able to get the instance of pbjs in my vue component. But trying to figure out on how to render the ad's in vue.

- Any suggestions or ideas on how to integrate it in nuxt ?
- **Where exactly to initiate the prebid script code and script code for slots ?**
- **Is it okay to use the prebid.js as a plugin in nuxt ?**
- Is there a vue-library that can help in rendering the ad's ?